# Simplify "If" statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, case, selection

I have a rather large `If` statement.

```
If Node1.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = HomeNode
    ' Main week views
ElseIf Node2.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wk1
ElseIf Node3.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wk2
ElseIf Node4.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wk3
ElseIf Node5.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wk4
    ' Week 1
ElseIf Node6.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = mon1
ElseIf Node7.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = tue1
ElseIf Node8.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wed1
ElseIf Node9.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = thu1
ElseIf Node10.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = fri1
    ' Week 2
ElseIf Node11.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = mon2
ElseIf Node12.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = tue2
ElseIf Node13.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wed2
ElseIf Node14.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = thu2
ElseIf Node15.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = fri2
    ' Week 3
ElseIf Node16.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = mon3
ElseIf Node17.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = tue3
ElseIf Node18.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wed3
ElseIf Node19.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = thu3
ElseIf Node20.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = fri3
    ' Week 4
ElseIf Node21.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = mon2
ElseIf Node22.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = tue2
ElseIf Node23.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = wed2
ElseIf Node24.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = thu2
ElseIf Node25.IsSelected Then
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = fri2
Else
    CrumbBar1.SelectedItem = HomeNode
End If
```

I know about `Select Case` statements, but can this `If` statement be simplified using one?

I was taught in college while using Delphi that case selection only worked with single characters and integers. Is this the same across all/most languages?

To reassure people I will be renaming all of the nodes and `CrumbBar1` to something more meaningful, they're just temporary names.

The nodes are part of a `TreeView` control, and the `CrumbBar` is a component like that seen in Windows Explorer as it's address bar.

Comment: VB.NET is not Delphi so that lesson does not apply.  In fact, SELECT CASE is pretty flexible and powerful in VB.  What are these things though?  If the poorly named `NodeXX` objects have a Tag property you may be able to stash the related object there and set the SelectedItem from that.

Comment: A Case Select statement would work just fine, except that it doesn't make the code any prettier.  This went off the rails when you decided to create 25 "Node" variables.  Why you need a TreeView *and* a CrumbBar is hard to guess.

Comment: Another option would be a `Dictionary` to map Nodes to Crumbs.

Answer (score 2):

`If` statements that are either overly long or overly complex are a good [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) for re-examining how you are approaching the problem.

There are many ways this could be refactored, and I'd have to see more of the original code to truly understand what you are doing here. (What are `mon1`, `mon2` - objects? Strings?)

Consider storing all of the items you are putting into `Crumbar1.SelectedItem` into an array. Then, you could do something like `CrumbBar.SelectedItem = items[x]` where *x* is an index of the selected item in the TreeView. (Or, do all of this in the TreeView `OnSelectedItem` event.)

If you post more of your code or more details about the problem you are trying to solve, I'd be happy to update my answer with a more complete code solution.

Comment: These variables are the members of a CrumbBar control, similar to the address bar in Windows Explorer. What this system does is change the crumbbar's selected item based on which node (with the same hierarchy of items) in the treeview. Mon1 etc refer to which day of which week, so mon1 is monday week 1. This system is a five-day, four week calendar, the treeview and crumbbar are used to filter down the calendar to just the specified day or week